# Realm Xamarin LINQ Object

Tags: linq, xamarin, realm

What is the correct way to query Realm with LINQ where the query includes fields from other Realm objects? For example:

```
public class Department : RealmObject
{
    [Primary Key]
    public string UniqueId { get; set; }
}

public class Employee : RealmObject
{
    [Primary Key]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    // Parent
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Then I would expect to be able to do something like:

```
var employee = realm.All<Employee>().SingleOrDefault( e => e.Department.UniqueId == fooId && e.Name == fooName );
```

But this always returns no matches. Where() also returns no matches. However, eliminating the e.Department and searching only on employee name works fine but obviously does not scope to Department as intended.

This is with the latest Realm Xamarin 0.80.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Querying by nested `RealmObjects` attributes is not currently supported:

> Just to clarify here, we don't yet support queries on related objects like this. We will in the future, but there is no timeline at the moment.

The following is also **not** currently supported:

```
var deptFilter = theRealm.ObjectForPrimaryKey<Department>("HR");
var employeesByDept = theRealm.All<Employee>().Where((Employee emp) => emp.Department == deptFilter & emp.Name == "StackOverflow");
```

> The left-hand side of the And operator must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm.
>   Unable to process '(emp.Department == value(Realm080.App+c__AnonStorey1).deptFilter)'.

You can do direct `RealmObject` equalities, just not in the same `Linq` expression, so break it down further into a sub-query.

#### Example of how I currently do it:

```
var deptFilter = theRealm.ObjectForPrimaryKey<Department>("HR");
var employeesByDept = theRealm.All<Employee>().Where((Employee emp) => emp.Department == deptFilter);
var employees = employeesByDept.Where((Employee emp) => emp.Name == "StackOverflow");
foreach (var emp in employees)
{
    D.WriteLine(emp.Name);
}
```

Note: https://github.com/realm/realm-dotnet/issues/723

Comment: Perfect, thanks. A little more cumbersome than I was hoping, but does the trick. And I am now realizing that in many of these situations, I can just iterate on someDepartment.Employees directly to search for a match rather than running a query. I assume that would be faster than the LINQ query?

Comment: @BSohl The "query" is not evaluated until you actually *access* the `RealmObjects` by performing a `.ToList`, .`ToArray`, `foreach (.. in ..){}`, etc... so it is **faster** to do the sub-query on the emp's name vs. performing the `foreach` on all the employees in the department as each object has to be accessed while you do the equality comparison in C# vs. doing it at the `Realm.Core` (C++) level. Personally I always *try* to filter to the smallest dataset possible for the fastest response and the smallest memory overhead and then bring those `RealmObjects` to the C# level for attribute acces

Comment: Anybody reading this after today should know that `ObjectForPrimaryKey` was deprecated and replaced with the `.Find` command, which provides the same function.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm-sdks/dotnet/latest/reference/Realms.Realm.html#Realms_Realm_Find__1_System_Nullable_System_Int64__