# How can I query a RealmList with Realm (v0.80) for Xamarin dotnet?

Tags: c#, realm

I have 2 classes:

```
public class Invoice : RealmObject
{
   public int Id;
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public IList<Product> Products { get; }
}


public class Product : RealmObject
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do a query where I can list all invoices containing a specific product?

I would code my LINQ query as such but I get an unsupported exception:

```
realm.All<Invoice>().Where(i => i.Products.Any(p => p.Name == "product 1"));
```

I can do it this way but then getting the invoice count for each product takes way too long.

```
realm.All<Invoice>().ToList().Where(i => i.Products.Any(p => p.Name == "product 1"));
```

I've tried anything I could think of but it just doesn't work.

Any help is welcomed because listing all products with a count of how many invoices it's included in really takes forever.

Comment: This looks relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330887/realm-xamarin-linq-object/40331608#40331608

Comment: Thanks, I had checked that one but it is not the same thing. Looking in a One-to-Many IList<T> that is my problem. Querying using Contains or Any doesn't work. My only option is iterating through each element of the list, but that is very slow and beats the purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the latest version (0.81.0), we added support for [inverse relationships](https://realm.io/docs/xamarin/latest/#inverse-relationships). So you can modify your model slightly like:

```
public class Product : RealmObject
{
    /* other properties */
    [Backlink(nameof(Invoice.Products))]
    public IQueryable<Invoice> RelatedInvoices { get; }
}
```

and then you can query the invoices like:

```
var product = realm.All<Product>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "product 1");
var invoices = product.RelatedInvoices;
```