# Better workaround to search nested object in realm xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin, realm

I am trying to search nested object in realm but I get the following error

```
var contactList = realm.All<Contact>().Where( c => c.syncInfo.isSync == SyncStatus.NOT_SYNCED);
```

> System.NotSupportedException: The left-hand side of the Equal operator
>   must be a direct access to a persisted property in Realm.
>
> Unable to process 'c.syncInfo.isSync'.

***I am aware that this feature does not exist in `Realm Xamarin` but I am looking for better workaround.***

```
public class Contact : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Id {get;set;}

    public ContactName {get; set;}

    public SyncInfo syncInfo;
}

public class SyncInfo: RealmObject
{
    public int isSync { get; set; }     
    public long timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

so far I have tried using `ToList()` and `foreach` to find the record but I have 1000 contacts so using `ToList()` and `foreach` slows down the performance.

[I tried to refer this thread but no luck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330887/realm-xamarin-linq-object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like there's a one-to-one mapping between `Contact` and `SyncInfo`. So your best bet would be to merge them:

```
public class Contact : RealmObject
{
    [PrimaryKey]
    public Id {get;set;}

    public ContactName {get; set;}

    public int isSync { get; set; }     

    public long timestamp {get;set;}
}
```

This would improve the design as well, because you won't have to delete old `SyncInfo`s (e.g. when replacing the sync information on the contact).

Comment: i have 20 more model in which i didnt want to replicate `isSync` and `timestamp` field and in realm u can not extend other external class hence i thought to use the `SyncInfo` as a class member as a composition

Comment: and i didn't get this statement `you won't have to delete old SyncInfos (e.g. when replacing the sync information on the contact).` can you please explain

Comment: E.g. you have a `Contact` with `SyncInfo.isSync = false`. If you get a new `SyncInfo` from the server: `var updatedInfo = serverClient.GetSyncInfoForContact(contact.Id)` and assign it to your contact: `contact.syncInfo = updatedInfo`, the previous object will now be dangling - being unassigned to anything and will need to be deleted.

Comment: I understand your argument about not wanting to replicate properties in a lot of classes and it's a valid one, but it's one more field (since you're replicating the `SyncInfo` property anyway) and will simplify the design a bit.

Comment: I don't think that answer's the op's question, specifically how to query nested objects. Which this is not. Not sure why this has been marked the answer. Whether it works or not.

Comment: The OP was asking about a workaround as querying nested objects isn't supported. As there's no way to query them, I feel their best bet would be to flatten their hierarchy which is what the answer suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Try .Where(c => c.syncInfo.isSync == SyncStatus.NOT_SYNCED.isSync && c.syncInfo.timestamp == SyncStatus.NOT_SYNCED.timestamp)

Comment: this will not going to work as you will get error `Where(c => c.syncInfo.isSync == SyncStatus.NOT_SYNCED.isSync` gets executed

Answer (score 0):

Can you do something like this maybe. Store the contact in the sync info.

```
public class SyncInfo: RealmObject
{
    public Contact contact { get; set; }
    public int isSync { get; set; }     
    public long timestamp { get;set; }
}
```

Then query like this:

`var unsyncedContacts = realm.All<SyncInfo>().Where(s.isSync == SyncStatus.NOT_SYNCED).Select(s => s.contact);`